# Access Update Statement And Calling Said Statement Within .NET

Tags: .net, ms-access, sql-update

I am working with an Access database which I really do not enjoy by the way, and am trying to perform an update on a record with a "contacts" table. The statement is written like so...

```
UPDATE contacts SET FirstName = [c_FirstName], LastName = [c_LastName], Title = [c_Title], Email = [c_Email], IncludeSection4 = [c_IncludeSection4] WHERE (((ContactID)=[c_ContactID]));
```

Now the .NET part goes like this...

```
Public Shared Function Update(ByVal contact As IContact) As Boolean
        Dim parameterList As New List(Of DataParameter)
        parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_ContactID", contact.ContactID, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.Integer))
        parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_FirstName", contact.FirstName, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.VarChar))
        parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_LastName", contact.LastName, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.VarChar))
        parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_Title", contact.Title, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.VarChar))
        parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_Email", contact.Email, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.VarChar))
        parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_IncludeSection4", contact.IncludeSection4, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.Boolean))
        If DAL.SendData("UpdateContact", parameterList) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
End Function
```

For some reason, this does not update and always returns false. cmd.ExecuteNonQuery always returns 0.... I'm thinking that the Access part of it is not correct, is there anything obvious here?

Comment: Are you sure the contact id exists?  Also, include your DAL.SendData code.  Also, which version of Access?

Comment: Yup, all was good, just the order of parameters was wrong since when working with Access the names of the parameters are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OleDb with Access ignores the parameter names.  Supply the parameters in the same order as they appear in the `UPDATE` statement.

```
    parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_FirstName", contact.FirstName, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.VarChar))
    parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_LastName", contact.LastName, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.VarChar))
    parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_Title", contact.Title, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.VarChar))
    parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_Email", contact.Email, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.VarChar))
    parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_IncludeSection4", contact.IncludeSection4, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.Boolean))
    parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("c_ContactID", contact.ContactID, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.Integer))
```

Comment: Damnit, I knew this! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your update statement looks odd.  It's been a long time since I've done access, but it should look more like this:

```
UPDATE [contacts] SET [FirstName] = @c_FirstName, [LastName] = @c_LastName, ...
```

Also, you Access doesn't really care about the parameter names, just make sure they're in the same order.